# ICS CalendarContract RDATE format?

Tags: android

i am trying to add a recurring event to a google calendar in ICS.
The code works for adding a single event but i do not seem to be able to get the correct format for the end date.

This is my code

```
  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY");
  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RDATE, "20120325");
```

What would be the correct format for the RDATE string assuming an end date of 4/25/2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows the RDATE spec -
http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rdate.html